# On uploading from next.js frontend, image is uploaded on cloudinary but not on strapi backend, how to resolve this problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, file-upload, strapi

System Information
Strapi Version: 4.11.1
Operating System: Windows 10
Database: SQLite
Node Version: 18.16.0
NPM Version: 9.5.1

On uploading a image from next.js frontend, image is uploaded on cloudinary but not on strapi backend, which shows 500 internal server error, on fetching the image. I’m using fetch() method like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("files", image);

  formData.append("ref", "events");

  formData.append("refId", evtId);

  formData.append("field", "image");

  console.log("formData: ", formData.get("files"));

  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/upload`, {

    method: "POST",

    body: formData,

  });
```

this method uploads the image on cloudinary, but I don’t see the image on the strapi media library.
before implementing this image upload feature everything was working fine, but after this I’m getting this type of response in browser console from the server, which is not exactly an error:

[image: Response on browser Console on upload button clicked.]

this is the error I get in my server console, which says: “error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
‘attributes’)”:
[image: Error on upload button clicked on server console.]

my plugins.js file in strapi backend is like this:

```
 module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'cloudinary',
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
        api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
        api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
  
  slugify: {
    enabled: true,
    config: {
      contentTypes: {
        event: {
          field: 'slug',
          references: 'name',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  
});
```

and middleware.js is like this:

```
module.exports = [   
    {
      name: 'strapi::security',
      config: {
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
          useDefaults: true,
          directives: {
            'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
            'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', 'market-assets.strapi.io', 'res.cloudinary.com'],
            'media-src': [
              "'self'",
              'data:',
              'blob:',
              'market-assets.strapi.io',
              'res.cloudinary.com',
            ],
            upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'strapi::cors',
      config: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:1337', 'https://subdomain.example.com', 'https://someotherwebsite.org'],
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
        headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
        keepHeaderOnError: true,
      },
    },
  
];
```

Please help me in resolving this error as soon as possible. Thanks.